# Кускус — без дефиса?

Tags: слитно-дефис, дефис

В орфографических словарях слово "кускус" в значении "животное" пишется слитно. Но если оно обозначает крупу, сохраняется ли такое написание? Дефисное написание также довольно частотное. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Дефисное написание также довольно частотное

В серьезных текстах не встречал. Но если такое и происходит, то объяснить могу только ошибочным осмыслением этого слова.
Это не одно слово, два раза повторенное, это просто два совпадающих слога одного слова. Мотивов для дефиса нет никаких.

Возможно, сыграло свою роль закрепленное орфографически написание сим-сим. Но это, пожалуй, единственный случай, когда через дефис пишется слово из двух одинаковых частей, но не являющееся смысловым удвоением своих половинок. Но и это объясняется прихотью переводчика, отошедшего от привычной фонетической интерпретации арабского названия кунжута - сезам. Скорее всего тут виною попытка внести звукоподражательный эффект. В этом случае дефис оправдан. Есть и другие, совсем уж диковинные версии, но и в них не обошлось без удвоения.

В отношении же кускуса ничего, даже отдаленно похожего на удвоение, не наблюдается: к одному или двум "кусам" значение кускуса не сводится никаким образом.

Comment: "Сезам" из латыни, а "симсим" по-арабски "кунжут".

Comment: *"Сезам" из латыни* - Да, но это только последняя фаза. На самом деле восходит к семитским языкам, откуда посредством греческого попало а латынь. . В арабском оно тоже представлено.  Симсим - это там уже вторично. Да и огласовка скорее "сэмсэм" Короче это отдельный разговор. А что касается версии про переводческую блажь, так она есть даже в вики.. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC,_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8F

Comment: *Да и огласовка скорее "сэмсэм"* — а ещё точнее, просто schwa вместо Э. Кстати, египтянин тут говорит всё-таки через И: https://forvo.com/word/%D8%B3%D9%85%D8%B3%D9%85/#ar.

Comment: )))) Я слышу именно Сэмсэм. А вот шва не слышу в принципе. Могу только добавить, что гласные в арабском сильно повержены диалектным изменениям. Тому много причин, но вот переход полного в сверхраткий - это уже отдельная история, связанная с изменением значения слова. Так что принимать, что там шва я бы не советовал.

Comment: Ну не буду принимать.)) Хотя по моей ссылке она мне слышится в озвучке мужчины из ОАЭ, а вот Э — да, тоже слышится у женщины на масри (ниже). А у мужчины из Египта, озвучивающего на классическом, слышу И. Нашёл, кстати, это слово с огласовками, так там как раз и стоят две кясры под س (симсим): سِمْسِمٌ.

Answer (score 0):

[Кускус (кулинария)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%81_(%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F))

> Куску́с (бербер. ⵙⴻⴽⵙⵓ, араб. كسكس‎) — пшеничная крупа, которая служит
>   основой для одноимённого блюда магрибского или берберского
>   происхождения.
>
> Исторически кускус готовили из проса. В наше время наиболее
>   распространён кускус из манной крупы, получаемой из твёрдой пшеницы.
>   Внешне напоминает круглый рис, диаметр крупинок — 1—2 мм.
>
> ---

[**Кускус** — название многих сумчатых животных из подотряда двурезцовых сумчатых, в том числе род кускусов (Phalanger); фактически синоним слова поссум.](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%81)

[**Кускус** — крупа, приготовляемая из пшеницы, а также блюда из неё, популярные на востоке.](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%81)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

***[Кускус, или Привет из Северной Африки](https://www.edimdoma.ru/kulinarnaya_shkola/posts/16812-kuskus-ili-privet-iz-severnoy-afriki)***